# Is lucene index created with 2.3.1 compatible with Lucene 3.0.3

Tags: lucene

We have indexed our documents with Lucene 2.3.1 and now want to move to Lucene 3.0.3 for better features. I want to know whether the index will work as is and will I be able to add more documents, with 3.0.3, to the existing index without any hassles or do I have to re-index the whole thing.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am quite sure that the indexes will be incompatible with Lucene 3 if they were built under Lucene 2 (in fact I'm 99% positive of this).

However, you may be able to convert them rather than rebuild them. Have a look [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/java-user@lucene.apache.org/msg30264.html) for some high-level guidance in this area.

Comment: Thanks Brent. That article was very informative. As it mentions, the change seems to be only in the string compression. If I had not used any compression at all (Field.Store.COMPRESS), then it should not be an issue I think. Am I right ?

Comment: Based on the article it would seem that you are correct. Best to give the upgrade a try (maybe on a branch of your code base) and see what happens. I think it will work out to be quite simple in your case.

Comment: The key note is that he's using a really old version in the 2.x branch. I believe that the newest version of the 2.x writers (2.9.x) would write indexes that 3.0 readers can work with, but not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks Brent and Simon. I will give direct switch a try, or else go 2.3.1 -> 2.9.4 -> 3.0.3, readers first and then writer.